# How to align a column to other column with blank spaces in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying a spreadsheet wherein you input days, workouts and how many times. And it automatically logged your time in and out.

I made it like if the day is input the time start is logged and when new time day is input on another cell(same column) time ends is logged. My problem is that when my activities stack in the distance between my time start and end becomes large. Is there a way to just put them near each other?

Like time start is in A1 and time ends will be in B1 rather than it is to B3 or so?

I put my code in a7 and b7 for the auto time logging. Hope you understand what I'm saying xD. Thanks in advance

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OlJt7Y9xSATve8tqOg6GPhz1pWtnhm5SckBcqDgwGc8/edit?usp=drivesdk) is the link.

Comment: you need timestamp script

Comment: Ok the formula I done works just, the time end is not align with the time start. I search the timestamp script and I think I'm having a hard time to understand it. But anyways thanks for the info will probably try it in future.

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly you need. I looked at the document you shared and it still wasn't too clear to me. Could you explain exactly where the problem lies?

Comment: Apologies for that, I tried to improve my sheet a little, I'm doing it on phone so I don't know how to change the sheet setting for it to work.

Comment: What I want to happen is for the inputs of B to be align to A. I code it like if the current cell in C is blank but the cell below the current is not blank and  both the current cell of D and E is not blank it will record the time end.

Comment: Would an answer based on [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) work for you? You can automatically process when a cell/column is edited and make operations based on that change.